# If you are a master of Image processing and Opencv -- can you use it to replace photoshop?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, photoshop

If you are a master of image processing and OpenCV, can you code up most of the main functions of photoshop instead of paying for it?

Comment: You can use GIMP instead of Photoshop. If you really want OpenCV-stuff in it you can simply create plugins for GIMP and add the missing functionality. Photoshop has other goals then OpenCV. This leads different approaches to various problems starting from the data structures used for storing image data, the algorithms etc. etc. and finishing with things like user interface (`highgui` is there only for the very basic usage to display stuff and allow very limited interaction). My answer would be a "no" especially since we don't know what Photoshop has under the hood (closed source and all that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You certainly can. You can also build your own house, grow your own food, and make your own clothes, instead of paying for the ready-made ones. But is that practical? Probably not...

Comment: ...yet some do: [How to Make a $1500 Sandwich in Only 6 Months](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URvWSsAgtJE) I think the conclusion of this video can match the conclusion of writing a Photoshop clone using OpenCV.

Comment: ...and I seriously doubt that one person can write a Photoshop clone in 6 months. :)

Comment: ...and with $1500 :))

Comment: hahaha I see what you mean. But I mean for basic stuff, like blur or sharpen your image, it is just a few lines of code in python. But yeah maybe photoshop is a bad comparison, I wonder what if it is compared to more basic software, like ACDsee

Comment: @wudanao That's what we have open source for. There's a lot of free stuff with high quality that you can contribute to instead of starting from scratch.